Let $ f(x) $ be a function that has a first-order derivative on the interval [0,1], and $ f^{(n)}(0) = 0 $ for all $ n \geq 0 $.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Let } f(x) \text{ be differentiable on } [0,1], \text{ with } f^{(n)}(0) = 0 \text{ for all } n \geq 0. \\
& \text{Given that for all } x, |x f'(x)| \leq 2023|f(x)|, \\
& \text{prove that for all } x \in [0,1], f(x) = 0. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
My attempt:I attempted to first prove that f(x)=0 on a small interval of fixed length around 0, and then extend it to [0, 1], but I'm unsure how to estimate. I tried using the Mean Value Theorem but didn't achieve the desired result.

Set $K=2023$. For all $x \in [0, 1]$ is
$$
 x f(x) f'(x) \le x |f(x)f'(x)| \le K |f(x)|^2 = Kf(x)^2 \, .
$$
Now consider the function $g:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 g(x) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ for } x = 0 \, ,\\
 (x^{-K} f(x))^2 & \text{ for } 0 < x \le 1 \, .
\end{cases}
$$
Repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule and the condition $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$ shows that
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x^K} = 0 \, ,
$$
so that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$. Also $g$ is nonnegative and decreasing, since
$$
 g'(x) = 2x^{-2K} f(x) f'(x) - 2K x^{-2K-1}f(x)^2 \\
= 2x^{-2K-1} \bigl(x f(x)f'(x) - K f(x)^2\bigr) \le 0
$$
for $0 < x \le 1$. It follows that $g$, and consequently $f$, is identically zero.
